# Split String Java Calculator

Tags: java, string, split, calculator

I have this code

the error is within the if statements regarding -, * and / operations "The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String" can anyone help

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you try to **divide a string** and why? More generally, what do you expect to happen when you perform arithmetic operations on a string and why? I might also recommend performing a cursory Google search for your error for some hints on why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: You will have to parse the string to retrieve a number. You'll probably want to use something like `int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);`

Comment: You probably want to parse the other two strings as numbers.

Comment: @NikG Integer is not the correct data type to use here.

Comment: @tnw Based on the prompt string (`Enter your two numbers and the operation with spaces between e.g 8 9 -`), Integer would work just fine. If he wanted to handle decimals, then he would use Double.parseDouble(). I'm only giving quick and dirty examples - there's a reason I posted as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @NikG No, integer would not work just fine. The last if-statement uses division.

Comment: @tnw It's perfectly legal to divide two integers, and since OP isn't actually doing anything with the answer in the code he posted, we can't assume we know what he wants to do with it.

Comment: @NikG Just because you can doesn't mean you should. Suggesting using integers for division is terrible advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse each of parts to perform mathematical operation on them. You can not do such operations on strings (but you can concatenate strings with '+', but not sum). Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter your two numbers and the operation with spaces between e.g 8 9 -");

        String calculation=scan.nextLine();

        String [] parts = calculation.split(" ");

        int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int part2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        int answer;
        String operation = parts[2];
        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                answer = part1 + part2;
                break;
            case "-":
                answer = part1 - part2;
                break;
            case "*":
                answer = part1 * part2;
                break;
            case "/":
                answer = part1 / part2;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Incorrect operation: " + operation);
        }

        String ans = String.valueOf(answer);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }    
}
```

If you want to print incorrect operation symbol, you have to modify program. First of all we need to initialize integer **answer** variable to '0' and you need to create new boolean variable that will flag operation correctness.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Enter your two numbers and the operation with spaces between e.g 8 9 -");

        String calculation=scan.nextLine();

        String [] parts = calculation.split(" ");

        int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int part2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        int answer = 0;
        boolean incorrectOperation = false;
        String operation = parts[2];
        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                answer = part1 + part2;
                break;
            case "-":
                answer = part1 - part2;
                break;
            case "*":
                answer = part1 * part2;
                break;
            case "/":
                answer = part1 / part2;
                break;
            default:
                incorrectOperation = true;
        }

        String ans;
        if(incorrectOperation) {
            ans = "Incorrect operation: " + operation;
        } else {
            ans = String.valueOf(answer);
        }

        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: that works great! is there any way i could display the 'Incorrect operation' error using 'System.out.println' as well ?

Comment: Don't use integers for division or arithmetic in general. This should use `Double`s or something like it instead.

Comment: @tnw yes I know. But may be Zak's task imply using integers here for arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using Integer.parse(), why not just use scanner.nextInt() in your use case?

```
    int part1 = scan.nextInt();
    int part2 = scan.nextInt();
    String operation = scan.nextLine().trim();
```

Comment: i need the 'throw new' to be displayed using 'System.out.println'

Comment: @ZakRatcliffe you can throw new wherever you want....I'm sure there is a chapter in your text book called "Java Exception"